# Create a user with all privileges but grant

Tags: mysql, sql-grant

When I create a user with all privileges on a table but grant privilege, I use the following commands:

```
mysql> grant all privileges on table.* to 'foo'@'localhost' identified by 'bar';
mysql> revoke grant option on table.* from 'foo'@'localhost';
```

Is there a way to do it with only one command?

Comment: Yup, mention all the privilages except `grant` in a comma seperated list, instead of `all`

Comment: This seems to be the most compact, rather than listing out every privilege except for grant.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of giving all privileges and revoke some privileges by commands.

The only option is to specify all privileges as comma separated list in GRANT command.

> Also in GRANT command we have database_name.*   instead of 
>   table_name.*

For a specific table we have to specify like:
 db_name.table_name  instead of db_name.*

Thanks